# assign custom list by value memory allocation in c# list object assignment issue

Tags: c#, list, linq, object

```
objTempList = objParentList;
foreach (var item in objTempList)
{
    objChildList = objList.AsQueryable()
                          .Where(x => x._parentId == item.filedbid)
                          .ToList<FileObjectView>();
    if (objChildList != null)
    {
        foreach (var child in objChildList)
        {
            objParentList.Add(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Above is my code,  problem is the assignment of `objTempList = objParentList`

`objParentList` has 10 rows which are assigned to `objTempList`
now in next step when i am doing `foreach` and adding more rows in `objParentList`  its automaticaly reflecting in list `objTempList` and my loop is giving error message.

Comment: Please use `code formatting` when posting code in questions. You have given `objTempList` a reference to `objParentList`, anything the parent list gets, the temp list will get too. What is the specific error you get? It would be useful to know...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should separate list instances to avoid this error

```
objTempList = objParentList.ToList();
foreach (var item in objTempList) 
{ 
   objChildList = objList.AsQueryable().Where(x => x._parentId == item.filedbid).ToList(); 
   foreach (var child in objChildList)
      objParentList.Add(child);       
}
```

Comment: The error was that modifying a collection while iterating through it is an invalid operation. As objTempList and objParentList were the same object in the code from the question, it failed to add objects to objParentList while iterating through it.

Comment: InvalidOperationException. In the original version objTempList was modified as it was the same reference as objParentList.

Comment: yes its same reference but then how to assign two list object without reference

Comment: and i am not using keyword ref anywhere then why its referring parent instance

Comment: do you want changes in objParentList to be reflected in objTempList after enumaration finishes?

Comment: no i dont want to reflect the changes i assigned it to objTempList  just to run foreach

Comment: Then you can just look at the difference between your code and the one in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign the contents of `objParentList` to `objTempList` without inadvertently modifying `objTempList` inside your foreach loop, then you need to create a new instance of of `objParentList` and assign that to `objTempList`.

That way, adding list items to the parent list inside of the loop will not throw an exception since you assigned a copy of the original to `objTempList` and not a reference. For example:

```
objTempList = new List<T>(objParentList);
```